# Disposing of EF DbContext with ninject, when moving away from using statements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject, idisposable

I am working with `SQL server 2008`, `.NET4.5`, `MVC4`, `EF6` and `Ninject3.2`.

I have application that needs to be migrated to use DI with Ninject. `DbContext` that has to be injected in to Controllers is `OnlineLegal`.
Currently it is used following in each of Actions.

```
 using (var db = new OnlineLegal())
            {
    ...
            }
```

This makes it clearly visible where `OnlineLegal` is being used and disposed of.

**If I would set up ninject** `kernel.Bind<OnlineLegal>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();` **would this be sufficient to make sure that it is [disposed properly on each request](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope) in MVC4? If not should I [manually register](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope#user-content-manually-registering-oneperrequestmodule-in-webconfig-eg-if-youre-not-using-a-ninjectwebmvc-nuget-package) `OnePerRequestModule`? Or use some other way to do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient. Provided you have installed the [Ninject.MVC4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC4/) package ;-).

However, there's recently been quite a few question about `InRequestScope` not working. I think currently the ninject setup is a bit error prone to mistake and/or issues with package installation/upgrade routines.

As such i would recommend to use `.InRequestScope()` but also add one (exemplar and automated) integration test which verifies that `.InRequestScope()` actually properly performs the disposal.
That will show you that you've integrated it correctly and if in future there should be trouble with package upgrade routines you'll find out immediately and can fix it, rather than finding out in production or through some obscure effects.

Documentation link: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope

Ninject.MVC4 depends on Ninject.Web.Common.Webhost. Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost adds [NinjectWebCommon.cs](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/tree/master/nuget-webhost) code to your application's app_start folder. 
NinjectWebCommon.cs loads the `OnerPerRequestModule`. However if you remove that file you will break `.InRequestScope()`. The bad thing about this is, that it fails without exception. You can still bind `.InRequestScope()` but it just won't have any effect.

Comment: I thought it will be sufficient just needed Ninject expert to confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I've extended the answer a bit to show how it works and why it can be dangerous.

Comment: Make sure that you update your Ninject.Web.Common package to the newest version.